# TemplateRenderer does not render beans

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin-flow, vaadin10

I'm trying to use `TemplateRenderer` where I want to propagate models to front-end.

```
userGrid.addColumn(TemplateRenderer.<UserProjection>of(
        "<user-card"
                + " userDetail='[[item.userDetail]]'"
                + " licenses='[[item.licenses]]' "
                + " test='[[item.test]]'"
                + " id='[[item.id]]'"
                + ">"
                + "</user-card>")
        .withProperty("userDetail", user -> user)
        .withProperty("licenses",
                user -> userService.findAllUserLicenses(user.getId()).stream().map(License::new).collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .withProperty("test", UserProjection::getEmail)
        .withProperty("id", UserProjection::getId)
);
```

this is my template:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">

<link rel="import" href="../../styles/shared-styles.html">


    <dom-module id="user-card">
        <template>

            <div class="content" on-click="_onClick">
                <div>[[test]] [[id]] [[userDetail.id]] </div>
                <div class="user-details">

                    <h1>[[userDetail.firstName]] [[userDetail.lastName]]</h1>
                    <h3>[[userDetail.email]]</h3>
                </div>
                <dom-repeat items="[[licenses]]">
                    <div class="license">
                        {{item.validTo}}
                    </div>
                </dom-repeat>
            </div>

        </template>
        <script>
            class UserCard extends Polymer.Element {
                static get is() {
                    return "user-card";
                }

                _onClick() {
                    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('card-click'));
                }
            }

            window.customElements.define(UserCard.is, UserCard);
        </script>
    </dom-module>
```

and `user-card` template is also included in template where I'm using the grid. I can successfully display properties `test` and `id` however I'm unable to work with `userDetail` and `licenses`. Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong? I'm using vaadin `13.0.5`.

Comment: Could you try to add `<template>` to `dom-repeat` of licenses? At least, all examples I've found  has it [Dom-repeat](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/api/elements/dom-repeat). Not sure about the first issue, through

Comment: (Could you try to rename the `userDetail` to something else for testing purposes? Does it work this way?)

Comment: Hi, I used `template` for `dom-repeat` and also renamed `userDetail` to `superDetail` and changed that in parameter and also in template but nothing works.

Comment: Alrigth, then it's something else. But thanks for checking

Comment: I just resolved that...it's about weird naming in template. Instead of 
 `userDetail='[[item.userDetail]]'` I renamed html attribute to `user-detail='[[item.userDetail]]'` and now it works. I have overlooked that, or maybe that just could be mentioned somewhere in vaadin documentation.

Comment: It's nice you have found it! But, indeed, I haven't seen/found myself any mention that `-` should be used